# Calculate change over time with tidy data in R - do you have to spread and gather?

Tags: r, time-series, tidyr

Quick question about calculating a change over time for tidy data. Do I need to spread the data, mutate the variable and then gather the data again (see below), or is there a quicker way to do this keeping the data tidy.

Here is an example:

```
df <- data.frame(country = c(1, 1, 2, 2), 
                 year = c(1999, 2000, 1999, 2000), 
                 value = c(20, 30, 40, 50))
df
  country year value
1       1 1999    20
2       1 2000    30
3       2 1999    40
4       2 2000    50
```

To calculate the change in value between 1999 and 2000 I would:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df2 <- df %>% 
  spread(year, value) %>% 
  mutate(change.99.00 = `2000` - `1999`) %>% 
  gather(year, value, c(`1999`, `2000`))

df2
  country change.99.00 year value
1       1           10 1999    20
2       2           10 1999    40
3       1           10 2000    30
4       2           10 2000    50
```

This seems a laborious way to do this. I assume there should be a neat way to do this while keeping the data in narrow, tidy format, by grouping the data or something but I can't think of it and I can't find an answer online.

Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After grouping by 'country', get the `diff` of 'value' filtered with the logical expression `year %in% 1999:2000`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(country) %>%
   mutate(change.99.00 = diff(value[year %in% 1999:2000]))
# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   country [2]
#  country  year value change.99.00
#    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>        <dbl>
#1       1  1999    20           10
#2       1  2000    30           10
#3       2  1999    40           10
#4       2  2000    50           10
```

NOTE: Here, we assume that the 'year' is not duplicated per 'country'